# Informal of "Fixing problem is in progress"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

We have comical picture which we show when video signal is lost. The text below should be sort of that: "No signal. Fixing is in progress". But in more informal way. One alternative is: "No signal. We are on it". Your alternatives?

Comment: In the old days of broadcast television, one common wording was "Transmission difficulties. Please stand by."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No signal. Fixing's **underway***.

> underway: currently in progress [Wordnet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underway)

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is it correct "We are on it" in english?

Comment: @AlexEx: "We are on it" is a shortened form of the idea "We are working on it." I imagine that most English speakers recognize the equivalence of the two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

> No signal. Fixing it now.
>
> No signal. Being fixed now.